# Problem 9 page 92 from A book of set theory by Pinter

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Let E and F be partially ordered classes, and let g : E → F be an isomorphism.

Prove that for arbitrary x$\in E$,

g($S_x$)=$S_{g(x)}$

**Attempted proof v1.0**

By hypothesis g is an isomorphism,g is bijective.By Theorem  4.1.14every element g($S_x$) in E has a corresponding element $S_{g(x)}$ in F(So I have to create such
a 1-1 map)

But first Image of g is defined as:

```
       g[E]={g(x)|x $\in $E}
```

*Now my mapping*

x $\mapsto$ g(x)

$S_x \mapsto $g($S_x$)

g($S_x$) $\mapsto $ $S_{g(x)}$

Since x,y $\in E  $ then $S_x, S_y$ are two initial segments of class X.

if x < y, then$S_x$ is an initial segment of $S_y$ and$S_x$ ⊂$S_y$;

Since g is in increasing and by theorem 4.1.1
x <y $\iff$ $S_x < S_y \iff$g($S_x$)< $S_{g(x)}$

Help .

Comment: What is $S_x$? Is that everything less than or equal to $x$?

Comment: 4.5 Definition Let E be a partially ordered class and suppose x ∈E. The initial segment ofE determined by x is the class $S_x$ defined as follows: $S_x$={x € E| x<X}

Comment: @william eliot ok what I did say in my attempted proof ?

Comment: @HomerSimpson.  Examine the third line.

Comment: Part of the def of isomorphism